# Custom member_action in Rails ActiveAdmin is not able to redirect to other routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a Rails 6.1.7 app using Active Admin 2.13.1, for which I'm trying to create a custom member_action called `:ensure_subtitles`, but the redirection is proving troublesome. Everything I've tried for my `:ensure_subtitles` action is failing to redirect, either resulting in an error  or no actual browser redirection.

I have another custom member_action, albeit with the `:update` name, and that redirects to the resource path/the show page without issue.

This is the form with the view:

```
    <%= form_with(model: video,
                  namespace: :admin,
                  url: ensure_subtitles_admin_video_path(video),
                  method: :post) do |form| %>
      <% video.subtitle_collections.sort_by(&:language).each do |sc| %>
        <%= form.check_box sc.almanac_language_code_id %>
        <%= form.label sc.language %>
        <br />
      <% end %>

      <%= form.submit('Resync selected captions') %>
    <% end %>
```

This is my app/admin/videos.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Video do
  decorate_with VideoDecorator

  menu if: proc { current_user.is_admin? }, priority: 1

  actions :index, :show, :edit, :ensure_subtitles

  member_action :ensure_subtitles, method: :post do
    resource
    redirect_to resource_path(format: :html), notice: 'Ensured subtitles'
  end
end
```

What happens in my browser is that it stays on the current view WITHOUT following the redirect -- I've looked at my local logs and it does show the 302, and then serves the show page **but as an XHR request** (per Chrome's developer console), meaning that the browser doesn't change pages and remains stuck on the form.

I also want to point out that if I don't specify `format: :html` in the redirect, the logs show this:

```
Processing by Admin::VideosController#ensure_subtitles as JS

...

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/videos/135165
Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms | Allocations: 12914)
...
::1 - - [09/Mar/2023:10:56:32 PST] "POST /admin/videos/135165/ensure_subtitles HTTP/1.1" 302 107
http://localhost:3000/admin/videos/135165/resync_subtitle_collections -> /admin/videos/135165/ensure_subtitles
Started GET "/admin/videos/135165" for ::1 at 2023-03-09 10:56:32 -0800
Processing by Admin::VideosController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"135165"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 72 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 87ms (Allocations: 6261)



NoMethodError (undefined method `access_denied' for #<Admin::VideosController:0x00000000097b30>

        instance_exec(self, exception, &active_admin_namespace.on_unauthorized_access.to_proc)
```

And I don't think this is an permission issue because I threw a byebug in the action definition and ran this:

```
(byebug) authorized? :ensure_subtitles, resource
true
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with some help from a colleague: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

> In Rails 6.0 and 5.2, all forms using form_with implement remote: true by default. These forms will submit data using an XHR (Ajax) request. To disable this include local: true. To dive deeper see Working with JavaScript in Rails guide.

So my use of the `form_with` was adding a `data-remote='true'` HTML attribute to my form, which was causing havoc because the requests were being treated as XHR instead of document requests.

The comment also suggests that this behavior isn't in Rails 7 anymore, though I'd be curious if that indeed is the case.